# How to create lists of sublists?

Tags: c#, list

I'm new in C# and I don't find easy references to understand how working with lists of sublists.

I have a list called "mainlist" defined as

```
List<List<double>> mainlist = new List<List<double>>();
```

mainlist includes four lists made by numbers so I have:

```
mainlist[0] which is {1,1,1,1,1}
mainlist[1] which is {2,2,2,2,2}
mainlist[2] which is {5,5,5,5,5}
mainlist[3] which is {3,3,3,3,2}
```

Now I want to create a new list called "biglist" composed by:
biglist[1]
biglist[2]

within biglist[1] I want to include mainlist[0] and mainlist[1] while into biglist[2] I want mainlist[2] and mainlist[3].

My goal is to understand how to declare and create lists of sublists.
I read that it's possible to declare List

```
List<List<List<double>>> xxx = new List<List<List<double>>>()
```

If I write xxx[1][2][0] I'm accessing to what? Is [2] the row, [0] the column and [1] the number of the list??

I come from Matlab and there if I had a 3D matrix I declared it like MATRIX(X,Y,Z) where X were the rows, Y the columns, Z the submatrix I wanted to refer inside the big matrix MATRIX. 
I'd like to understand how it's possible to have this in C#.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: whats the issue, you're declaring them properly, the only thing you need to do after that is initialize each list and each lists list's

Comment: There is no row or column. There is simply an index number for each element. If you lay them out graphically you can transpose them to rows or columns, but that depends on whatever technique you utilize to convert to a graphical view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would instantiate your biglist and populate it with the sub-list from mainlist like so

```
var biglist = new List<List<List<double>>>();

// add mainlist[0] and mainlist[1]
biglist.Add(mainlist.GetRange(0,2);

// add mainlist[2] and mainlist[3]
biglist.Add(mainlist.GetRange(2,2);
```

To answer your question about how `biglist[x][y][z]` works, it means you are accessing index `x` of `biglist` (which contains your sub-lists), index `y` which pulls up one of the indices of `mainlist`, and then index `x` will pull element `x` of that `mainlist` element.

For example,
`biglist[0][1][0]`
will pull up `mainlist[1][0] = 2`

Answer (score 0):

you should not be requiring list at all. your requirement can be met with multi dimensional arrays

```
 decimal[][][] matrix3D = new decimal[10][][];

            for (int i = 0; i < matrix3D.Length; i++)
            {
                matrix3D[i] = new decimal[10][];

                for (int j = 0; j < matrix3D[i].Length; j++)
                    matrix3D[i][j] = new decimal[10];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using nested lists will only confuse you and others who will read this code. Even if I see `List` of `List` I always suggest to my colleges to rewrite it in some form that does not require such constructs.

If you want to represent matrices you can use arrays.
There are 2 types of arrays in C#

- Multidimensional Arrays with syntax of `int[,,]` for array of int. They can store rectangular matrices.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays

- Jagged Arrays with syntax of `int[][][]` for array of int. As they can store variable-length arrays in different dimensions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays